# Dynamically selecting an autoexec file for batch processing in SAS

Tags: sas

Can anyone please provide advice or a step by step solution to the below problem.

The issue I am faced with is one where I have 2 sets of raw data in one study, one set for MRD and one for Neuro. I have created 2 separate autoexec files to read in the correct data into the interactive SAS session. But when it comes to batching the programs SAS does not assign the correct library locations for the data.

What I need to do is scan the directory path of the file that is being batched for MRD or Neuro and then direct the batching process to use the associated autoexec.sas file for either MRD or Neuro. All of this needs to happen before the batching process starts so that the correct libraries are assigned.

The process that my company follows to load the autoexec.sas files is as follow;
1. The SAS shortcut includes a custom call to a file called biosetup.inc.
2. Biosetup.inc includes the study path directory of the autoexec.sas file.
3. Autoexec.sas assigns the library names and paths to be used in the    interactive SAS session as well as setting up the paths for macros etc.

The way I think I need to approach this is to create a macro inside of the biosetup.inc that will assign the correct autoexec file.

Is this at all possible?

So far I have been able to determine the directory path etc, and now what I still need to do is make sure that the correct autoexec file is being used.

```
%macro MAIN;
%let proctype = %scan(&SYSPROCESSNAME,1,%str( ));

/*Define macro variable for the path and filename*/
%if &proctype = DMS
%then %let pathpgmref=%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH);
%else %let pathpgmref=%sysfunc(GetOption(SYSIN));

/*Define separate macro variables for the filename.extension, filename, and extension*/
/*Reverse path and filename to scan from the front (back)*/
%let pathpgmref = %sysfunc(reverse(&pathpgmref));
%let pgmextref = %scan(&pathpgmref,1,\);
%let extref = %scan(&pgmextref,1,.);

/*Reverse back to proper order*/
%let pathpgmref = %sysfunc(reverse(&pathpgmref));
%let pgmextref = %sysfunc(reverse(&pgmextref));
%let extref = %sysfunc(reverse(&extref));
%let pgmref = %scan(&pgmextref,1,.);

/*Remove filename to create program directory macro variable*/

%let temp = %eval(%index(&pathpgmref,&pgmref) - 1);
%let pathref = %substr(&pathpgmref,1,&temp);

%let PATH = %sysfunc(quote(&pathref));
%let EXTN = %sysfunc(quote(&extref));
%let PGMN = %sysfunc(quote(&pgmref));

Data _Null_;
    if index(&PATH,"MRD") and lowcase(&EXTN) = "sas" then call symput("DATATYPE","MRD");        
    else if index(&PATH,"NEURO") and lowcase(&EXTN) = "sas" then call symput("DATATYPE","NEURO");
    else if index(&PATH,"Listings") or index(&PATH,"Tables") and lowcase(&EXTN) = "sas" then do;
        if lowcase(substr(reverse(&PGMN),1,1)) = "a" then call symput("DATATYPE","MRD");
        if lowcase(substr(reverse(&PGMN),1,1)) = "b" then call symput("DATATYPE","NEURO");
    end;
Run;

%if &DATATYPE = "MRD" %then %do;
    %include "MRD_Setup.sas";
%end;
%if &DATATYPE = "NEURO" %then %do;
    %include "NEU_Setup.sas";
%end;

%put ProcType: &proctype;
%put FullPath: &pathpgmref;
%put DirePath: &pathref;
%put FullFile: &pgmextref;
%put FileName: &pgmref;
%put ExtnType: &extref;
%put DataType: &DATATYPE;
%mend;

%MAIN;
```

Comment: When you say 'scan the directory path' you mean `determine what the path to the .sas file is`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend simply passing in a parameter via the `-SYSPARM` command line option.

```
sas mysasfile.sas -AUTOEXEC biosetup.inc -SYSPARM "path_of_autoexec_to_run"
```

And then in your sas program I think you should be able to do this:

```
%include "&sysparm";
```

This assumes that you're not currently using `-SYSPARM` for anything else.  It also assumes you have 2 shortcuts, 1 for each study.  From your question it sounds like that's how it is currently setup.

I haven't tested this but in theory this should work.

[Here's a working example](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543608.htm) (from the documentation).